# Excel VLOOKUP - How to use column name instead of column number?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm creating what should be a fairly simple VLOOKUP function where it compares two spreadsheets in identical format (but potentially different data, think new salaries, new department etc.). Now, the formula I've created works - but only for one column. The problem I'm encountering is that the '8' in the two VLOOKUP statements does not go to a '9' when I drag the formula to the cell next to it (and in turn it would go to '10', '11', '12' etc.).

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A15,Old!$A:$R,8,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A15,New!$A:$S,8,FALSE),"",New!H15)
```

Is there a way to get the column number in the VLOOKUP statement to +1 each time I drag it across to a new column? Everything else does, such as New!H15 turns into New!L15 etc.

If not, is there a way to get the column name to replace the column number? Column names would have to be in cell format as they are all different e.g. instead of saying "Business Unit" it would say H1 etc.

If this isn't possible, can my statement be done via an INDEX IF MATCH statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **column** function to return the column number of the column where you are entering the formula. Then add or subtract depending on which column number you want to return. Assuming you are entering the formula in column B and you want to return a value from B:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A15,Old!$A:$R,column(),FALSE)=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A15,New!$A:$S,column(),FALSE),"",New!H15)
```

Assuming you are entering the formula in column C (which is column 3) and you want to return a value from B, you subtract 1 from the column formula so that it returns 2:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A15,Old!$A:$R,column()-1,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A15,New!$A:$S,column()-1,FALSE),"",New!H15)
```